# Disabling spaceless inside a block inside a {% spaceless %} tag

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have a Twig block called `content` to render all the actual content of the web page.  This block is placed inside a `{% spaceless %}` tag.

```
{% spaceless %}
    ... some HTML ...
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    ... more HTML ...
{% endspaceless %}
```

The `content` block is replaced by actual content.  For example:

```
{% block content %}
    ... some HTML ...
    <article>
        Some text with <em>a tag</em> <strong>and</strong> <em>another tag</em>
    </article>
    ... more articles, sections, etc. ...
{% endblock %}
```

This specific example is rendered as

```
<article>
Some text with <em>a tag</em><strong>and</strong><em>another tag</em></article>
```

where all the  spaces between the consecutive tags are removed because of the `spaceless` tag.  This is obviously an unwanted side-effect.

Is it possible to (temporary) disable the `spaceless` functionality inside a `block`?  It will not work to incorrectly nest the `spaceless` tag, i.e.,

```
{% block content %}
    ... some HTML ...
    <article>
        {% endspaceless %}
        Some text with <em>a tag</em> <strong>and</strong> <em>another tag</em>
        {% spaceless %}
    </article>
    ... more articles, sections, etc. ...
{% endblock %}
```

because that will throw an exception:

> Unexpected tag name "endspaceless" (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the spaceless tag does something it shouldn't do maybe you should remove it then or set a condition that it does show only if it is needed. Just give it a thought.. ;)

On the other hand, you could try this of course:

```
{% spaceless %}
... some HTML ...
{% endspaceless %}    
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% spaceless %}
... more HTML ...
{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: I guess your answer is that what I want isn't possible. There is no other solution than to reorder my `spaceless` tag. It isn't possible to disable the `spaceless` property for, let's say, span HTML elements?

Comment: I've changed my structuring of the template includes and removed the `spaceless` tags around blocks.

Comment: I know of no way you can tell Twig to handle specific HTML tags differently for it's own "Filters". :(